# Samba share only works debug/interactive

Tags: samba

I set up a very simple samba share:

```
[files]
        path=/data
        browseable = Yes
        read only = No
        writable = Yes
        force user = nobody
```

Unfortunately, when I try to access the folder 'files' samba gives this error in the logs:

```
[2022/01/08 16:23:02.713103,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:787(make_connection_snum)
  make_connection_snum: canonicalize_connect_path failed for service files, path /data
```

However, if I run samba interactively and with debug on:
`smbd -d 9 -F -i`

It works just fine. Which makes this difficult to troubleshoot.

Not sure what the problem is, assuming it's some kind of permission but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: Is selinux enabled on your system? If you're not sure, try running the `getenforce` command and let us know the result.

Comment: It sure is! I bet that is  related to the issue. I probably have to run something on my data directory to fix it up.

Comment: The `smbd_selinux` man page has some useful information (part of the `selinux-policy-doc` package).

Comment: Got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that selinux was enforcing and the appropriate context needed to be set on the directories.